# How to check if user press the reply keyboard button? telegram bot python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Easy task, but I can't figure out how to do it.
I'd like to check if user press the button 'Add variants' to add next messages from user to list `variants`. I tried to do it using `if message.text == 'Add variants'`, but it just adds to the
list text 'Add variants' one time and that's it. Is there any way to check if user click the button and after that add next messages from user to list?

```
variants = []

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'welcome'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item_1 = types.KeyboardButton('Random')
    item_2 = types.KeyboardButton('TradingView')
    item_3 = types.KeyboardButton('Weather')
    item_4 = types.KeyboardButton('Other')
    item_5 = types.KeyboardButton('Back')
    markup.add(item_1, item_2, item_3, item_4, item_5)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose', reply_markup = markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message(message):

    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Random':
            
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            item_1 = types.KeyboardButton('Add variants')
            item_2 = types.KeyboardButton('Back')
            markup.add(item_1, item_2)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose', reply_markup = markup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of code you dont add anything to 'variants'. But as I understood: after user clicks 'Add variants' button you want to handle new message from user and add this message to a 'variants'. If so you need to register next_step_handler  after you handeled 'Add variants' message.

Like that:

```
variants = []


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message(message):

    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Add variants':
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Send me variant")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, handling_variant)


def handling_variant(message):
    variants.append(message.text)
```

[here](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py) is example of using next_step_handler

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I wanted. It works now. But it adds only one message. Do you know how to add several messages?

Comment: It looks like all code which is connected with buttons stop works, when I start typing something.

Comment: You just have to edit your code. I have shown you this method register_next_step_handler(), now do with it whatever you want.  Also you can find method that stops next step handler. Im not sure mb it is clear_step_handler(). Good luck!